# tabularx and multirow: Strange Behaviour

Tags: tabularx, multirow

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left = 5mm,
    right = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Thicker table lines for screenshot
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myTableColor}{gray}{0.80}

% Nice sf font for screenshot
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163061
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Red Text Causes Strange Column}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
& & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{130mm}{\centering Text}}} & \\ 
% New Row
& & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \\ 
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
Text & Text & & & & \textcolor{red}{Problem Column} & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text Text Text Text \textcolor{red}{Text} & Text & Text Text Text Text Text \textcolor{red}{Text} & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\section*{Red Text Removed}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
& & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{130mm}{\centering Text}}} & \\ 
% New Row
& & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \\ 
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
Text & Text & & & & \textcolor{blue}{No Problem Column} & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text Text Text Text & Text & Text Text Text Text Text & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

### MWE Output

[image]

### Problem

- I have a table in which I use `tabularx` and `multirow`.
- When I add the red text in the MWE then I get a shift in one of the `X` columns.
- I don't understand what happens.

### Update

After the chat in the comments, I think that this may be the better question:

> Can I use a `multirow` and `multicolumn` with automatic line break without having to
>   specify the width explicitly (here 120mm)?

### "Real" Table

This is the "real" table.

[image]

Comment: it seems that the width of `\parbox` in `multirow` cell is wider than sum of column width below of `multicol` cell in which you have `multirow`. If you will reduce its width from 130 mm to 90 mmm (as example), your problem will disappear. Or I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: @Zarko I thought that `X` columns have all the same width. I am confused that it affects only one column. **Question:** Can I use a `multirow` with automatic line break *without* having to specify the width explicitly (here `120mm`)? And thanks for the comment.

Comment: you have used \multicolumn which by design replaces the column specification from the table preamble by the specification for this cell, so here you have a fixed width `p` column with a fixed width that is wider than the natural width of the columns being spanned, in such a case the tex `\halign` primitive always adds the excess width to the last spanned column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the explanation/clarification.  I updated the question.

Comment: I don't suppose you're tempted to follow egreg's advice? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127114/dynamic-table-multirow-with-xstring-macro/127160#127160

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I won't argue with you or egreg :). I "want" an automatic line break if possible. I have to go to bed now -- eyes are closing automatically. Can't think straight anymore.

Comment: meanwhile I will try to find the answer of @Mico, where he solve similar problem.

Comment: @Zarko see below:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you save my time to search mentioned answer. I remember, that I use similar approach a while ago, but I'm tired to ... (night is for slipping, isn't it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a Y column for your spanning entry

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left = 5mm,
    right = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Thicker table lines for screenshot
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myTableColor}{gray}{0.80}

% Nice sf font for screenshot
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163061
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Red Text Causes Strange Column}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
& & & 
\multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}Y}
{\multirow{2}{=}{\centering Text 
text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text
}} & \\ 
% New Row
& & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \\ 
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
Text & Text & & & & \textcolor{red}{Problem Column} & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text Text Text Text \textcolor{red}{Text} & Text & Text Text Text Text Text \textcolor{red}{Text} & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\section*{Red Text Removed}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|Y|Y|Y|Y}
& & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{130mm}{\centering Text}}} & \\ 
% New Row
& & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \\ 
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
Text & Text & & & & \textcolor{blue}{No Problem Column} & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text Text Text Text & Text & Text Text Text Text Text & & & & \\ \hline
% New Row
Text & Text & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in order to have a `parbox` with the natural length of the `multicolumns` I have to use`\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}Y`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes three X columns would be 3\hsize but you are spanning two column separators each of which is a space or tabcolsep, a rule of width arrayrulewidth and another tabcolsep space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it should be pointed that text in `multirow` cells should not be longer then two lines, otherwise it will protrude into rows below this cell.

Comment: @Zarlo well the multi row entry has to be smaller than the rows spanned